# intergral involving crossproduct of vectors

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

Please explain can we take crossproduct outside integral.

$$
\int(\vec{a}×d\vec{b})=\vec{a}\times\int (d\vec{b})=(\vec{a}\times\vec{b})
$$

When $\vec{a}$ is constant with respect to $b$. I am facing a problem that is initially in integral angle between the vector was varying where that part is gone.Is it correct to take a cross product outside integral if one is constant can please explain me why can we do this?

Comment: Either use mathjax or just simply write the things, We can edit that. But please don't leave it like that, it is just unreadable and ambiguous.

Comment: Are you trying to write, e.g., $\vec a$?  If so, the relevant syntax is "\vec a".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cross product is distributive, namely it satisfies $\vec{a} \times (\vec{b} + \vec{c}) = \vec{a} \times \vec{b} + \vec{a} \times \vec{c}$. If you think about the integral as the limit of a sum, you can see why this is true: $$\int\vec{a} \times\vec{db} = \lim_{\|\vec{\delta b_i}\| \to 0} \bigg( \sum_{i=0}^n \vec{a} \times \vec{\delta b_i} \bigg) = \vec{a} \times \Bigg( \lim_{\|\vec{\delta b_i}\| \to 0} \sum_{i=0}^n \vec{\delta b_i} \Bigg) = \vec{a} \times \int \vec{db}$$ where the $\vec{\delta b}_i$'s are components of an approximation to the vector $\vec{b}$. The angles do not matter, because ultimately you will get the same answer as $\vec{a}$ is a constant.